# How Trigger Installing Question Popup on mobile device for a PWA?

Tags: mobile, popup, installation, progressive-web-apps

How can I prompt a `Installing Question popup` when some one access to my PWA on a mobile device?

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool?

Comment: yes it is a valid PWA, but i try on localhost and so it running over http

Comment: You need to use HTTPS for a valid PWA to trigger the prompt. There are free HTTPS hosts like http://Glitch.me where you could test that if needed.